# How to setup ContentType for Azure ServiceBus from Spring JMS

Tags: azure, jms, azureservicebus, spring-jms

I'm trying to use library `azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter` to send messages to topic. Everything works, however messages are being stored in subscriptions as `application/xml` type and I can't find the way how to setup this correctly to have them stored as `application/json`.
I've tried to configure message converter to send `ContentType` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads#payload-serialization) but that doesn't work either.

```
  @Bean
  public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    final MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter(){
      @Override
      protected TextMessage mapToTextMessage(Object object, Session session, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
          throws JMSException, IOException {
        final TextMessage message = super.mapToTextMessage(object, session, objectWriter);
        message.setStringProperty("ContentType", "application/json");
        return message;
      }
    };
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return converter;
  }
```

[image: message]

Comment: Content-Type needs to be stored as a System Property for SB to properly recognize it. The setStringProperty() seems to just set a User Property. Question is: how can do write a system property in JMS. Didn't find something quickly

Comment: Try with `content_type` instead.

Comment: content_type doesn't work either :/

Comment: @bilak How did you set ContentType. Are you able to get it working?

Comment: @SathishMurugesan see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/18852#issuecomment-773922436)

Comment: @bilak did you ever make it work? I've only come up with a custom byte array message converter for my specific case so far, but it doen't really makes me happy.

Comment: @SergVasylchak [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/18852#issuecomment-773922436)

Comment: Thanks @bilak, pretty much the same I've come up with. Looks like there is no way to send json text messages with correct headers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exposed means of setting the content-type on the messages sent from the Qpid JMS client.  The client itself uses this field as part of the JMS mapping to AMQP to distinguish certain message types that it sends and to determine at receive time what certain messages should be presented as.

It is technically possible to use reflection to reach in and so the value but the APIs you have to use from the JmsMessageFacade class are not public and could change with any release so choosing to do so comes with significant risk.

Comment: well, you are [not right](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/18852#issuecomment-773922436)