# How to set ContentType in qpid JMS

Tags: jms, amqp, qpid

Hello this question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938223/how-to-setup-contenttype-for-azure-servicebus-from-spring-jms) and I'd like to know if there is any way to set `ContentType` header in qpid in JMS context. We are using `JmsConnectionFactory` and spring's JMS library.

I was trying to find some way using extension but can't find the way or if that's even possible.

```
    final org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory();
    jmsConnectionFactory.setExtension("headers", (connection, uri) -> {
      if (connection instanceof JmsConnection) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: FWIW, `JmsConnectionFactory` is an ambiguous identifier. You should specify the entire class name including the package so it's clear what actual class you're using.

Comment: it's qpid library, but yes I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

There is no exposed means of setting the content-type on the messages sent from the Qpid JMS client. The client itself uses this field as part of the JMS mapping to AMQP to distinguish certain message types that it sends and to determine at receive time what certain messages should be presented as.

It is technically possible to use reflection to reach in and so the value but the APIs you have to use from the JmsMessageFacade class are not public and could change with any release so choosing to do so comes with significant risk.

Comment: well, you are [not right](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/18852#issuecomment-773922436)